# Как сделать inline кнопку для повторного выполнения команды в телеграм боте на aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Делаю бот который по команде /random выдает случайный фильм из базы Кинопоиска. Хочу добавить кнопку которая повторяла бы выполнение команды, то есть выводила новый фильм.

Вот код команды random:

````
@dp.message_handler(commands=['random'])
async def random_movie_command(message: types.Message):
    try:
        request = requests.get(f'https://api.kinopoisk.dev/v1.3/movie/random', headers={'X-API-KEY': API_KEY})
        data = request.json()
        poster = data['poster']['url']
        name = data['name']
        original_name = data['alternativeName']
        if original_name is None:
            original_name = ''
        else:
            original_name = ' / ' + str(data['alternativeName'])
        year = data['year']
        rating = data['rating']['kp']
        genres = [genre['name'] for genre in data['genres']]
        countries = [country['name'] for country in data['countries']]
        description = data['description']
        link = f'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/{data["id"]}'
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Try again!', callback_data='refresh')
        keyboard.add(button)
        movie_descr =(
            f'{name}{original_name} ({year})\n'
            f'Рейтинг Кинопоиск: {rating} / 10\n'
            f'Жанры: {", ".join(genres)}\n'
            f'Страны: {", ".join(countries)}\n'
            f'\n{description[:350]+"..."}\n'
            f'\n{link}')
        await message.answer_photo(poster, caption=movie_descr, reply_markup=keyboard)
    except:
        await message.reply('Something went wrong. Try again in a while.')```
````

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'refresh')
async def process_callback_button(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    '''
    Хендлер для обработки нажатия кнопки поиска другого фильма.
    '''
    await random_movie_command(callback_query.message)
```